# Avoid duplication of state transitions in subsequent Google Unit Tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

Writing a set of unit tests where I wanna cover two different cases where the second case is a follow-up of the first case.

So here in the second case, would I have to duplicate the scenario to get to `STATE_A` so I could test the transition to `STATE_B` from it? Isn't there a way to invoke `testStateA` from within `testStateB`?

```
// first test
TEST_F(UtClass, testStateA)
{
  EXPECT_EQ(expectedState, STATE_0);    // default state 
  State0toA(); 
  EXPECT_EQ(expectedState, STATE_A);
}

// second test
TEST_F(UtClass, testStateB)
{
  EXPECT_EQ(expectedState, STATE_0);    // default state 
  
  State0toA();
  EXPECT_EQ(expectedState, STATE_A);
  
  StateAtoB();
  EXPECT_EQ(expectedState, STATE_B);
      
}
```

In the case above, if `State0toA()` fails, both the tests would fail despite the second test's intention it to mainly test `StateAtoB()`

Comment: The whole idea of unit tests is that they are supposed to be independent of order (a good test is to repeatedly run tests in a random order). The first step of any test is to setup the start condition of the test. If you have repeated functionality put it as a protected member function in the test class and reuse that function.

Comment: yes they are independent of order but it's just the idea of duplicating the code in a separate unit test that caught my attention, and felt it'd be a bad design

Comment: As Pepijn said, simply put the common duplicated code into a member function of `UtClass`.

Comment: DRY (don't repeat yourself) for code, WET (write expressive tests) for test code.  WET means the tests should be responsible for all of their arrange-act-assert, and suggests to prefer not to rely on common set-up and tear-down code (since that makes the unit tests themselves coupled to that set-up and tear-down).

Comment: +1 for WET. Having duplicated code in unit tests is encouraged if it improves readability. However, if this is something that you do in ALL of your tests, then you should probably put it in the `setUp` function of your [test fixture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJqRlSTQlh4&t=1337s).

Comment: sure the unit tests are meant to be independent but what if in `testStateB`, you duplicate the steps from `testStateA` in addition to testing the main feature and if `testStateA` fails, `testStateB` follows but this way `testStateB` didn't fail on the feature that it was supposed to test. Doesn't that trigger ambiguity for the sake of being "independent"?